# Enabled PS Remoting in local machine

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I am trying to enable PS-Remoting on my local machine using following command

```
Enable-PSRemoting
```

but it gives error as follows

[image]

as per above error I need to change the network connection type to either Domain or Private.
To check network connection type i have used following command

```
Get-NetFirewallProfile
```

it gives following result

[image]

I know about enable PS remoting without checking network profile using following command

```
Enable-PSRemoting -SkipNetworkProfileCheck
```

but it not solved my problem (such as create session with remote server). So, I would like to **enable PS remoting without skipping network profile check**

**Question(s) :-**

1. How can change the network connection type from Public to Private?
2. Is there any other way (such as make public profile inactive/disable) to enable PS remoting?
3. What is best practice to enable PS remoting without compromising security?

Comment: Set-NetConnectionProfile...

Comment: I have already tried "Set-NetConnectionProfile -Name Public -NetworkCategory Private" but it gives an error "Set-NetConnectionProfile: No MSFT_NetConnectionProfile objects found with property 'Name' equal to 'Public'.  Verify the value of the property and retry." but if you see in screenshot(in question) for public profile name is Public.

Comment: Do you want to remotely connect to another computer, or connect to your local computer remotely?

Comment: I trying to create session of remote server from my local machine and copy file to remote server from local machine using that session as follows
$server = 'xx.xxx.xxx.xx'
$username = 'xxxxx'
$password = 'xxx'
$pw   = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $pw)
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $server -Credential $cred
Copy-Item -Path "C:\test\oldFile.txt" -ToSession $Session -Destination "c:\test\newFile.txt"
$Session | Remove-PSSession
but for that I need to enable PS remoting on my local machine.

Comment: Do you get the same Error if you use `Enable-PSRemoting` in Windows Powershell 5 (5.1) instead of Powershell 6 or 7? Did `Enable-PSRemoting` work on the Server (you will need it there too)?  What Error do you get if you use `Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $Server -Credential`?

Comment: I haven't tried on PS5.yes it is enable on remote server.while it tried to create session on my local machine it gives error " ....the transport is HTTPS or the destination is in the TrustedHosts list, and explicit credentials are provided. Use winrm.cmd to configure TrustedHosts. Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated..." but i  have already set TrustedHosts to "All" on server.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from the comments.. that seems like a reasonable error, as you most likely don't have a network connection named "Public."

Run this to see any connection with a public profile.

```
Get-NetConnectionProfile | where networkcategory -eq 'public'
```

You will be able to see the names. However, if you just want to change it, you can pipe to `Set-NetConnectionProfile`

```
Get-NetConnectionProfile |
    where networkcategory -eq 'public' |
        Set-NetConnectionProfile -NetworkCategory Private
```

Comment: Thanks! using above get command I got public profile name and I set it to private using your set command. but after that also, if i trying to enable PS remoting it gives same error. I have tried to get all profile using command "Get-NetFirewallProfile" it shows me public profile as same as given in question (NetFirewallProfile)screenshot.

Comment: Yes that’s just a list of the possible profiles you can set a NIC to.

Comment: but after setting networkCategory to private it does not solve my problem. how can enable PS remoting?